# Proving that $\frac{d}{dt}x=\sqrt{|x|}+a$ has unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me with this question, please :

Given $a>0$,  I want to show that $\frac{d}{dt}x = \sqrt{|x|} + a $, with $x(0)=x_{0}$, has an unique solution.

The existence is granted by Peano's Theorem, but I'm having problems proving that there is uniqueness.

Comment: What do you mean by $x'$?

Comment: I mean $\frac{d}{dt}x$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x:(a,b)\to (c,d)$ is a solution for your problem, where $-\infty\leq a<0<b\leq\infty$. If $c\geq 0$ or $d\leq 0$ we are done, hence, suppose that $c<0<d$. We have that $$x'(t)=\sqrt{x}+a,\ \forall\ x\in (0,d)\tag{1}$$

Because $x'(t)>0$, we have that $x$ is increasing, hence, there exist unique $a_1\in (a,b)$ such that $x:(a_1,b)\to (0,d)$.

Let $\sqrt{x}=y$ and note that $x'(t)=2y(t)y'(t)$, which implies from $(1)$ that

$$2y(t)y'(t)=y(t)+a,\ \forall\ y\in (0,\sqrt{d}) \tag{2}$$

where $t\in (a_1',b')$. Now, you can integrate $(2)$ to find that there exist a unique $y$ which satisfies $(2)$ and hence there exist a unique $x$ which satisfies $(1)$. The other case is similar.

Comment: Muito obrigado Tomás.

Comment: De nada. Brasileiro?